# How to create a web component by using Flutter

Tags: flutter, web-component, flutter-web

My team has already created a web page with Flutter/Dart. It works, great! But it is now asked that the web page shall be integrated into a partner web site by means web components. That means we shall build our Flutter project into a web component instead of a web page.

Does anyone have an idea how we can achieve this? Thanks a lot!